# How to setup django without running server

Tags: python, django

i was trying to access django website from a remote server. 
I allowed all PC's in `settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', 'localhost']
```

And run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8085`
I can access the site from connected computers. But i need to run the `runserver` commanad on server system before accessing site. Is there a way to access the website without running the command

**Edit**: Server is windows

Comment: `runserver` is just the development server,  there are plenty of ways of running the site as explained in the deployment docs

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/

Comment: The document seems bit confusing. I m new in django. Is there any resource for reference

Comment: That *is* the resource. But there are hundreds of other tutorials out there.

Comment: I think all methods need to start server with commands

Comment: I would suggest dockerizing your django app. This will allow you to run your app on any server as long as it has docker and tools related to docker installed on it.

Comment: So please suggest an easy method

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to deploy Django but i don't know an easy method :-)

For all ways you need at least one thing: The webserver.

Common webservers are Apache2 and nginx.

I assume you use a debian based server (eg. Ubuntu).

If you choose apache2, install apache with:

```
sudo apt install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

---

Create the file with the hosts informations.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/foo.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This is name based virtual hosting. So place an appropriate server name
    #   here. Example: django.devsrv.local
    ServerName  {{ project_name }}.com
    ServerAlias www.{{ project_name }}.com

    # This alias makes serving static files possible.
    #   Please note, that this is geared to our settings/common.py
    #   In production environment, you will propably adjust this!
    #Alias /static/  {{ project_directory }}/static_root/
    #<Directory {{ project_directory }}/static_root>
    #    Options -Indexes
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Allow from all
    #</Directory>

    # This alias makes serving media files possible.
    #   Please note, that this is geared to our settings/common.py
    #   In production environment, you will propably adjust this!
    #Alias /media/  {{ project_directory }}/media/
    #<Directory {{ project_directory }}/media>
    #    Options -Indexes
    #    Order deny,allow
    #    Allow from all
    #</Directory>

    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias /   {{ project_directory }}/{{ project_name }}/wsgi.py

    # PROCESS_NAME specifies a distinct name of this process
    #   see: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess
    # PATH/TO/PROJECT_ROOT is the full path to your project's root directory, 
    #   containing your project files
    # PATH/TO/VIRTUALENV/ROOT: If you are using a virtualenv specify the full
    #   path to its directory.
    #   Generally you must specify the path to Python's site-packages.
    WSGIDaemonProcess {{ project_name }} threads=1 python-path={{ project_directory }}/:{{ path_to_virtualenv}}/lib/python{{ python_version }}/site-packages/

    # PROCESS_GROUP specifies a distinct name for the process group
    #   see: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIProcessGroup
    WSGIProcessGroup    {{ project_name }}

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog    ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ project_name }}_error.log
    CustomLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ project_name }}_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Replace:

- {{ project_name }} with the name of the project
- {{ project_directory }} with the directory path of your project
- {{ path_to_virtualenv}} with the path to your virtualenv
- {{ python_version }} with the pythonversion of your virtualenv

---

Run bash commands:

```
sudo a2ensite foo.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

If you have staticfiles which are not working, make sure you configured it correctly in settings.py:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), ]
```

then edit your foo.conf and restart apache again.

Comment: can i use the same in windows?

Comment: Not exactly the same way but it should work. https://www.codementor.io/aswinmurugesh/deploying-a-django-application-in-windows-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-uhl2xq09e